# Chrome malware scanner

Tags: chrome, malware

My Chrome has been frequently infected with unwanted extensions which I cannot remove. How do I prevent this?

I have tried the official Chrome Cleanup Tool but it's not useful.

Update: I am pretty sure these extensions are malwares. After installation my search bar got redirected very frequently.

On chrome they use "enterprise policy" and "installed by your administrator" to block me from uninstalling.

My antivirus software does not consider these "virus" though.

The extension is named "unTabs". It was installed automatically without my permission while I was opening a phishing package.

I would throw nuclear bomb over the head of the developer if I had chance.

Comment: Did you install these extensions yourself? Are these extensions using tricks to make themselves difficult to uninstall? Are these extensions actual malware, meaning an antivirus would try to delete them upon sight?

Comment: You may need to [delete your user profile](https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome+delete+user) in chrome (be sure not to restore extensions when you sign back in), but it sounds like removing it will not remove all of the effects. There is a discussion of what steps you can take to get things back to normal [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/V-b1-Jjkw2U).

Comment: As to your question, many anti-virus providers have browser extensions that will help you to keep an eye on things like this and provide a warning if something is trying to change settings or install an extension; that said, many people [recommend against using these](https://www.howtogeek.com/239950/dont-use-your-antivirus-browser-extensions-they-can-actually-make-you-less-safe/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While not only for Chrome, [AdwCleaner](https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/) by Malwarebytes is very much focused on removing browser garbage like Adware, bad extensions, hijacked settings and so on. I'd give that a try first.

Comment: Thanks. Malwarebytes worked for me before, but not this time, unfortunately.

Comment: @LowGPA, have you read my answer? I did not recommend **Malwarebytes** for you, but instead, I recommended **AdwCleaner** which is a completely different tool specifically geared towards browser stuff. The Malwarebytes team acquired it recently. Here is the link again https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/

Comment: Hi, I tried both for this time. None worked.

Comment: Then there's probably no easy fix/tool that can help you. You can try getting free help from the pros, at a site like https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/f/22/virus-trojan-spyware-and-malware-removal-logs/ or http://www.geekstogo.com/forum/topic/2852-malware-and-spyware-cleaning-guide/

Comment: Oh, I see that you already solved it. Great